# Using Virtual Folders within Eclipse PyDev Workspaces

Tags: eclipse, path, pydev, file-not-found, virtual-environment

I'm currently working through some Machine Learning tasks using Eclipse and PyDev.

This requires access to some large datasets of ~10K images. I didn't want to copy these large folders into the workspace, so the 'neat' solution seemed to be to import them as Eclipse 'virtual' folders (i.e. a link).

Several hours of processing later, this seemed to have worked...however, when I then try to access the virtual resources I generate:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\default\\training_set'
```

After stepping through, it became clear from using `os.listdir()` that whilst Eclipse may *show* virtual resources as being locally addressable, Python does not (shattering my vague assumption this would all be automatically handled by Eclipse).

My question is, within the PyDev environment, is there a way of using this functionality - or do I have to either fully import *all* my resources or use absolute file paths

Comment: Links are just something that Eclipse knows about, anything else won't see them.

Comment: I appreciate that...but I'm assuming that outside of PyDev, Eclipse wouldnt provide these if they couldnt be used!

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins that use the Eclipse workspace resource APIs can see these links. Plain programs in Python (or Java or anything else) don't see them.